# Angularjs, how to configure a module?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs but I believe I am past the basics and trying to understand some best practices now. With that said I am looking at a code, which I cannot fully understand:

```
 ciApp = angular.module("myApp", ["$strap.directives", "ngCookies"]).
    config(["$provide", function (e) {

        e.value("appVersion", "1.0"),
        e.value("appSupportUrl", "https://myknowledgeb as.com/")
    }
     ]).
    value("$anchorScroll", null).
    value("$location", null).
    run(["$rootScope", "version", "$log", function (n, ) {
        log.log("Starting my app")
    }
 ]);
```

What is the difference between calling module.config(["$provide", function (e) and setting services on the $provider and module().value("", ...)? And is there a difference at all?

Also is value("$anchorScroll", null) the best way to disable the $anchorScroll service?

Thanks

Comment: Short version, time of execution. Will give detailed answer tomorrow when i am back at a computer. Config fires first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular.js has five methods  different methods for creating services:

- factory()
- service()
- constant()
- value()
- provider()

I dont want to go deeper in the differences of each of this, in shortly I can say what

> If we want to be able to configure the service in the config()
>   function, we must use provider() to define our service.

and also

> The major difference between the value() method and the constant() method is that you can inject
>   a constant into a config function, whereas you cannot inject a value.

*form ng-book*